# python regex matching, findall or search do not return value

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a token out of a string and return it. I am using this method on other strings and it works fine, but this one does not seem to return any result. Not for findall and not for search.

```
pattern= re.compile(r'<input class="token"  value="(.+?)" name="csrftoken_reply">')
    matches = pattern.findall(htmlstring)
    for match in matches:
        print match
```

There is only one value in each response string. though I am not getting a result for "print match"

I also tried using re.search but same thing happens, a NoneType object is returned...

**MORE INFO:**

this is part of the html i'm parsing:

```
<form id="threadReplyForm" class="clearfix" method="post" action="/go/messages/private/threadID=0551796">
<input class="csrftoken" type="hidden" value="a7b161b7" name="csrftoken_reply">
<input type="hidden" value="reply" name="action">
<div class="editorWrapper">
<div id="premiumSmiliesNotAllowed" class="warning" style="display: none;">
<div id="editor_13" class="clearfix editor" mode="full">
<ul id="editorToolbar_13" class="editorToolbar clearfix">
<textarea id="messageInput" class="autogrow" cols="20" rows="8" name="message"></textarea>
<div id="previewDiv" class="previewArea" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
<script>
</div>
<script>
<span class="loadingIndicator right loadingIndicatorMessage">
<p class="clearfix">
</form>
```

parsing it with this :

```
pattern= re.compile(r'<input class="csrftoken" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" name="csrftoken_reply">')
    matches = pattern.findall(str(response.read()))
    for match in matches:
        print match
```

trying to get a7b161b7 as output

Comment: Maybe because you have two spaces after `class="token"`?

Comment: You have some whitespace errors there. Did you really mean for there to be two spaces between class and value?

Comment: please post (the section of) the html string you want to match and that doesnt match

Comment: Your two python snippets of code differ, which one is it that you are using?

Comment: Parsing html with regex is bad practice. Consider using specialized parser [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) for this task. `doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html_string); print doc.xpath('//input[@name="csrftoken_reply"]/@value')[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a Python person and not recommending regex to parse html, but it might be
possible to get unordered att-val data this way. Just put in some pairs that is
needed to qualify the tag. It doesn't have to be all of them or in any order.

Modifiers:  expanded, single-line string, global.
The value capture group is $5

**Edit**
Changed `(?= (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+` to `(?= (?:[^>"\']|(?>".*?"|\'.*?\'))*?` because lazy quantifier in this form will be forced to overrun markup boundries to satisfy the lookahead. The new sub-expression handles `attr="so< m >e"` embedded markup, without overruns.

```
<input 
  (?=\s) 
  (?= (?:[^>"\']|(?>".*?"|\'.*?\'))*? (?<=\s) class \s*=\s* ([\'"]) \s* csrftoken \s*\1 )
  (?= (?:[^>"\']|(?>".*?"|\'.*?\'))*? (?<=\s) name  \s*=\s* ([\'"]) \s* csrftoken_reply \s*\2 )
  (?= (?:[^>"\']|(?>".*?"|\'.*?\'))*? (?<=\s) type  \s*=\s* ([\'"]) \s* hidden \s*\3 )
  (?= (?:[^>"\']|(?>".*?"|\'.*?\'))*? (?<=\s) value \s*=\s* ([\'"]) \s* (.*?)  \s*\4 )
  \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ (?<!/)
>
```

All the caveats apply, could be hidden in imbedded code, could be comments, etc ...
Extra regex logic is needed for that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to give an example of the string you are trying to parse, because this works for me.

```
import re

htmlstring = """
<input class="token"  value="foo" name="csrftoken_reply">
"""

pattern= re.compile(r'<input class="token"  value="(.+?)" name="csrftoken_reply">')
matches = pattern.findall(htmlstring)
for match in matches:
    print match
```

Beyond that, have you considered using a library designed for something like this?  Regex's can be a big fragile when it comes to parsing html.  [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) seems to be a popular tool for this job.

*Update*

You've got a wrong class value, an extra space, and you forgot the 'input type="hidden"'.  Here's something closer, though I would still discourage use of regex for this:

```
r'<input class="csrftoken" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" name="csrftoken_reply">'
```

this works as well (I'm assuming there's one one 'csrftoken_reply' element):

```
r'value="(.+?)" name="csrftoken_reply">'
```

Both of these work for me to get your desired value.

Comment: by the way, i tested it at http://regexpal.com/ at there it seems to work and match fine. for some reason it doesnt using python

Comment: Hey, thanks all for the replies. I finally fixed it. The problem was that I was building my regex using output i got from FIREBUG, a firefox addon to inspect html. But firebug parses the html and places it in a sorted order before showing it. I found out when writing the parsed html to a file and saw that the output was different. Error on my side, sorry!

Comment: @SynbitzProwduczions Like I mentioned in my answer... regexes can be very fragile for this type of job.  With a true parser (like beautiful-soup) you shouldn't have that sort of problem.

Comment: I will take a look at beatiful-soup . I was using Mechanize until now

Comment: I'm not sure it'll replace mechanize, it's just better to parse the html than straight regex.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, parsing HTML with regex in 2011 is borderline insanity :) the number of libraries optimized for this task is quite large, the best ones being the above-mentioned BeautifulSoup and lxml; I can understand you wouldn't want to deal with lxml because of its list of dependencies and messy installation, but BeautifulSoup is **one file** and would make your code so much more robust.

TL;DR: you're reinventing the wheel.